# Do I need to specify --path on bundle install every time with multiple projects?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, bundler

I have multiple Rails applications. I am using `rbenv` to maintain my rubies, and leveraging `Bundler` to manage my gems for each project. I am not using any gemset functionality.

To install a project's gems, I do:

```
bundle install --path .gems
```

from each application's root directory. The Bundler docs state:

```
Bundler will remember this value for future installs on this machine
```

Well I don't want it remembered for the machine, just for each project. Does this mean that every time I do a `bundle install` on any of my applications that I should do the whole command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's remembered per-project in the `./.bundle/config` file.